# How to concatenate a json.dumps output with a string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mbox

**Summary**

I am attempting to concatenate the output of json.dumps - converting part dictionary variable, that has been passed from a client to a server, to a string - with a string, before passing it to a variable where it defines the name of a mbox file to be accessed.

**Variables defined**

The below variables are defined in the server's code.

```
recp_encoded = receive_message(client_socket)
recp = format(recp_encoded['data'].decode('utf-8'))
```

**Variables accessed**

```
json_user = (json.dumps(recp) + '.mbox')
print(json_user)
mailbox_name = str(json_user)
mbox = mailbox.mbox(mailbox_name)
mbox.lock()
```

However, the above code does not work as it formats the string as:

"user2".mbox'

Rather than the:

'user2.mbox'

That I need. In short, how do I fix the above to format the string to how I need it?

Comment: If you're receiving json, use json.loads, not json.dumps.  Although it seems you're just receiving a string.

Comment: Seems like the `resp` variable is just a string. If its a JSON you are expecting at `resp` then as @snakecharmerb mentioned, use `json.loads`. If you are not expecting a JSON then directly concatenate the string without passing it through any `json` function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that recp is a simple string type. Why not use the variable as given?

```py
json_user = recp_encoded['data'].decode('utf-8') + '.mbox'
```

Will this not give you want you need? It doesn't seem that recp is sent as a JSON.